# Select values from two different dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataset

i have a trouble when i'm dealing with my 2 dataset, i explain my problem:

I have 2 different dataset:

```
training_df = pd.read_csv('.../train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('.../test.csv')
```

I have to take values from some columns from train.csv and take other columns in test.csv, i tried like this:

```
num_attrib = pd.DataFrame(training_df, columns=[0, 2, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 24, 32, 34, 35, 36, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 54, 57, 59, 60, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72])
cat_attrib = pd.DataFrame(training_df, columns=[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40, 51, 53, 55, 56, 58, 61, 62, 63, 73, 74])

num_attrib_test = pd.DataFrame(test_df, columns=[0, 2, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 24, 32, 34, 35, 36, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 54, 57, 59, 60, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72])
cat_attrib_test = pd.DataFrame(test_df, columns=[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40, 51, 53, 55, 56, 58, 61, 62, 63, 73, 74])
```

Both datasets have numerical and categorial datas. I have to select and separate categorical from numerical datas for each datasets, but my way is wrong.
I have this trouble because i have to make the Columntransformer() on training_df and test_df.
Any suggestion?

Thank you so much

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please include sample output

Comment: Do you just have a source dataframe you are trying to split into training and test data?

Comment: I edited my post, maybe now is a bit more clear, i need to apply the Columntransformer on training and test set, because when i make the fit_transform it doesn't want categorical datas on test set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `iloc`. [See documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
num_attrib = training_df.iloc[:,[0,2,3,...,15]]
```

You can also slice:

```
#even columns
num_attrib = training_df.iloc[:, ::2]
#odd columns
num_attrib = training_df.iloc[:, 1::2]
```